# Environment variables within elasticapm.properties are not resolved

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-apm

```
src/main/resources/elasticapm.properties
server_url=${PROJECT_ELASTICAPM_URL}
```

Environment variables within elasticapm.properties are not **resolved** in runtime, when server url is passed as an ENV parameter to the service launched by docker. The following error is thrown instead

```
ch.client.WIRE       : [7f640f1e] Received raw response: 200 OK
2021-04-05 12:51:42,242 [elastic-apm-configuration-reloader] WARN  co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.stagemonitor.configuration.ConfigurationOption - Error in Attachment configuration: no protocol: ${PROJECT_ELASTICAPM_URL} Default value 'http://localhost:8200' for 'server_url' will be applied.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the value of the `server_url` via environment variables by providing a value for the variable `ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL` directly. For example:

```
environment:
  - ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME=backend-java
  - ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL=http://apm-server:8200
  - ELASTIC_APM_APPLICATION_PACKAGES=com.riferrei.backend.*
```

For more information about the configuration of the Java agent for Elastic APM:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/configuration.html